# java 8 Duration "ofSeconds" vs "withSeconds"

Tags: java, java-8, duration, java-time

With `Duration.ofSeconds(2)` we will get a `Duration` object representing 2 seconds.

Now if i have an instance of `Duration` and call the method `ofSeconds` on it is gonna return a new `Duration` instance with wiped out value other than nano seconds in it and the value I submitted as method parameter is gonna be set on it.

`Duration.ofHours(2).withSeconds(2)` will result in a `Duration` object representing 2 seconds.

Since the class `Duration` is immutable, what is the point of having a `withSeconds` method when I can simply use the static `ofSeconds`?

Answer (score 3):

See the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#withSeconds-long-):

> This returns a duration with the specified seconds, **retaining the nano-of-second part of this duration**.

Comment: Right. But It removes all the other information in the Duration. Isn't it kind of misleading? It seems as if the method would replace the seconds part of the Duration with the supplied value.

Comment: It’s low-level and not a method I’d normally use. While I want to think of a duration as an amount of time and not care about the implementation, it *is* implemented as a number of seconds and a number of nanoseconds, so they’ve provided a method where you can retain one and replace the other. I haven’t thought of a situation where you’d want that, but there probably could be one.

Answer (score 2):

`withSeconds` returns a new immutable object with overridden seconds. Everything else is retained.

`ofSeconds` creates a new immutable object based on the number of seconds.

Use the first one only when you want to *mutate* seconds without disregarding higher precision.